# Web sharing on Mavericks?

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks, web-sharing

OSX has removed "Web Sharing" as an option in Mavericks.

So how do I now view localhost on my Mac, from a phone connected to the same wireless network?

The advice I've read suggests starting Apache on the Mac:

```
$ sudo apachectl start
```

After that, I can load localhost on the Mac and see "It works!".

Then I run `ifconfig` to check my Mac's IP address, and then browse to that address on the phone browser.

But it does not work: I get 'Safari cannot open the page because it could not connect to the server'.

Help!

Comment: Try to disable the firewall if it's on.

Answer (score 3):

It's been removed from the non-Server version since Mountain Lion as far as I can tell.

As was stated in the comment, probably the only thing stopping you is the firewall.  You should be able to go into the Security Preferences pane, and in the Firewall tab, add a rule for `/usr/sbin/httpd`

As an aside, if you want the web server to be started automatically on reboot, you'll need to re-enable the Launch Daemon entry for it:

```
sudo defaults write /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd Disabled -bool false
```

(And you can disable it again by using `true` instead of `false` at the end there.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a web sharing error in Mavericks:

> Websites are turned off. An administrator can turn them on using the Server application

Unfortunately the Mavericks Server app won't run. But I found the Terminal command to make localhost work as normal:

```
sudo serveradmin start web
```

This should start Web Services in OS X Mavericks Server!

Comment: sudo: serveradmin: command not found